# How to tell Visual Studio 2005 a solution is already under source control

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tfs

I have a solution that is checked into our TFS source control repository, but when I open it in Visual Studio 2005 the padlock symbol that usually tells you it is under source control is missing. The effect of this is that when I save after performing an action in VS2005 that would typically force a solution file checkout (e.g. adding a new project) I get the following error:

> The file
>   xxx.sln
>   cannot be saved because it is
>   write-protected.
>
> You can either save the file in a
>   different location or Microsoft Visual
>   Studio can attempt to remove the
>   write-protection and overwrite the
>   file in its current location.

All the projects auto-checkout fine, and have the padlock icons beside they correctly too. I assume I just need to mark the solution as being under source control somehow.

Any ideas??

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to File->SourceControl->Change Source Control and set the binding of your project there to an appropriate location in TFS repository.

The link here ([Change Source Control Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt6fty90(VS.80).aspx)) will give you the details on how to deal with it.